# remove _id from mongo result

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm pretty new with mongo and nodejs 
I've a json as result of my query and I simply want to return the result as an http request, as following:

```
app.get('/itesms', function(req, res) {
  items.find().toArray(function (err, array) {
    res.send(array);
  })
});
```

It works, only problem is that I want to hide the _id fields (recursively) from the result. 
Any suggestion to do that in an elegant way?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try this solution:

```js
app.get('/itesms', function(req, res) {
  items.find({}, { _id: 0 }).toArray(function (err, array) {
    res.send(array);
  })
});
```

Comment: brilliant! simplest projection I ever saw :-)

Comment: This does not work for me... while the one below does

Comment: This solution doesn't work anymore with newest mongo module

Answer (score 38):

The usual `.find({}, {_id:0})` approach wasn't working for me, so I went hunting and found in [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50802269/993683) that in version 3 of the Mongo API, you need to write it like this: `.find({}, {projection:{_id:0}})`. So, for example:

```
let docs = await db.collection("mycol").find({}, {projection:{_id:0}}).toArray();
```

It seems that (in the nodejs API, at least) you can also write it like this:

```
let docs = await db.collection("mycol").find({}).project({_id:0}).toArray();
```

Comment: This is the correct answer now. Did this as a guess after logging the value of docs without the await and it showed up as a Promise. Wasn't made very clear in their docs.

Comment: This is what I needed.

Comment: If you're having trouble reading [the docs for how to suppress the `_id` field](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#suppress-_id-field), always make sure you go to the top-right corner of the web page and **select the language you are working with**.  MongoDB Shell syntax is indeed `.find({}, { _id: 0 })` but Node.js driver syntax is `.find({}, { projection: { _id: 0 } })`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't project inclusions and exclusions, ie you can't run a query with a 'project' statement that declares what should be included in the response as well as what must be excluded from the response.
From MongoDB [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/):

> A projection cannot contain both include and exclude specifications, except for the exclusion of the _id field. In projections that explicitly include fields, the _id field is the only field that you can explicitly exclude.

The way I handled this problem was to go to the end of the process, right before returning the response:

```
const dbObjectJSON = dbObject.toJson();
delete dbObjectJSON._id;
delete dbObjectJSON.__v;
...
response.json(dbObjectJSON);
```

Hope this helps.