# Node.js MongoDB Find with projection to exclude _id still returns it

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Trying to follow the examples [here](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_find.asp) to filter by using a projection to exclude _id. The _id still returns:

Code

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/db1";

MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbase = db.db("db1"); //here    

    dbase.collection("customers").find(
        {},
        {
            _id: 0

        }
        ).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        db.close();
    });

});
```

Result still return as follows:

> [ { _id: 5a2bb2d6ee48575cb54c4365,
>       name: 'John',
>       address: 'Highway 71' },   { _id: 5a2bb2d6ee48575cb54c436d,
>       name: 'Susan',
>       address: 'One way 98' },  ....   { _id: 5a2bb2d6ee48575cb54c4371,
>       name: 'Chuck',
>       address: 'Main Road 989' },   { _id: 5a2bb2d6ee48575cb54c4372,
>       name: 'Viola',
>       address: 'Sideway 1633' } ]

Theoretically _id should not be part of what is returned. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

To limit the fields you have to use `fields` option( dont know about new updates):

```
dbase.collection("customers").find({}, {
    fields: { _id: 0 }
}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    db.close();
});
```

UPDATE:

For version > 3 you have to use `projection` option instead:

```
dbase.collection("customers").find({}, {
    projection:{ _id: 0 }
}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    db.close();
});
```

Comment: Finally I find the answer I was looking for ! Any idea why I didn't find anything about this 'fields' key in the documentation ?

Comment: Finally find the answer as well. The official documentation does not state anything about the 'fields'

Answer (score 19):

In version 3 of the MongoDB API, the `fields` option has been deprecated. You should now use the `projection` option instead.

For example:

```
dbase.collection('customers').find({}, {
    projection: {
        _id: 0
    }
}).toArray(function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        throw err
    }

    console.log(result)
    db.close()
})
```

The full list of supported options can be found here: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#find

Answer (score 5):

Starting in version 3.4, there is now an option for adding .project() outside of find().

Using ES8 async,await.

Ex:

```js
async function connectDB(url) {

  try {
    const db = await MongoClient.connect(url);     
    const dbase = db.db("db1"); //here  
    
    const results = await dbase.collection("customers").find().project({_id:0}).toArray();

       console.log(result);
       db.close();
  }
  catch(err) {
    throw err;
  }
 }
```

Docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) and another example [here](https://www.nodejsera.com/library/nodejs-mongodb/projection-in-mongodb-using-nodejs.html).