# Printing MongoDB query values to console

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have written a particular query which fetches the Firstname from the users array from a document ,
the query successfully runs and displays in the MongoPlayground website but when I try to run the code in JavaScript and try printing to the console it gives me NULL or no output

```
 let dataset= await collection.find({
            "users.0.firstName": "Terry"
          },
          {
            _id: 0,
            "firstName": {
              $map: {
                input: "$users",
                in: "$$this.firstName"
              }
            }
          }).toArray();
          
          if(dataset&dataset.firstName)
          {
            for(let i=0;i<50;i++)
            {
                console.log(dataset.firstName[i])
            }
          }
```

tried removing the Toarry() method , tried without the loop but still doesn't give me any result

**MongoPlayground data**

[image]

Comment: can you also share the mongoplayground

Comment: @cmgchess I have added the image

Comment: cann u try like `collection.find({ "users.0.firstName": "Terry" }).project({ _id: 0, "firstName": { $map: { input: "$users", in: "$$this.firstName" } } }).toArray()`

Comment: @cmgchess nope, still the same , gives me undefined

Comment: can u also try like https://stackoverflow.com/a/47732107/13583510 `find({...}, { projection:{ ..... } }).toArray()`

Comment: oh by the way the if statement is incorrect since it returns an array. i think the answer below helps

Comment: @cmgchess even the below answer is not returning anything

Comment: @cmgchess found it , the above projection method works , Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your code to:

```
let dataset = await collection
    .find(
        {
            'users.0.firstName': 'Terry',
        },
        {
            projection: {
                _id: 0,
                firstName: {
                    $map: {
                        input: '$users',
                        in: '$$this.firstName',
                    },
                },
            },
        }
    )
    .toArray();

if (dataset && dataset.length > 0) {
    const firstNames = dataset[0].firstName;
    for (const name of firstNames) {
        console.log(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: it says `firstNames is not iterable`

Comment: thanks , I had to use the above gentleman's answers along with yours and I got the solution