# How can i delete _id properties?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

My problem is im trying to delete ._id when i show the contacts with all properties but for some reason if doesnt work.

```
app.get("/contacts", (req,res)=>{
var id = res.params._id;
contacts.find({}).toArray((err,contactsArray)=>{

    if(err){
         console.log("Error: "+err);
    }else{
        var arraySinId = contactsArray.map((t)=>{
           t.delete(id);
        });
        res.send(arraySinId); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you understand the purpose of function `map`?

Comment: Lol , transform an array in a new array

Comment: So, why are you using that way? are you aware of the implicit `undefined` value is being returned by the handler?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove \_id from mongo result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601219/remove-id-from-mongo-result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remap array into a new one with properties that you need. Check out code below.

```js
const contactsArray = [
  { id: 1, foo: 'foo'},
  { id: 2, foo: 'bar'},
  { id: 3, foo: 'baz'},
  { id: 4, foo: 'foobar'}
]

const arraySinId = contactsArray.map((t) => ({
  foo: t.foo,
}));

console.log(arraySinId)
```

**UPDATE**

In case the prop that has to be removed is dynamic you can use utility function `omit` that you can find in libraries such as Ramda or Lodash OR wite by your own.

```js
const dynamicPropToRemove = 'id'

const contactsArray = [
  { id: 1, foo: 'foo'},
  { id: 2, foo: 'bar'},
  { id: 3, foo: 'baz'},
  { id: 4, foo: 'foobar'}
]

const arraySinId = contactsArray.map(R.omit([ dynamicPropToRemove ]));

console.log(arraySinId)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Mm thats not working what i talking about. The "id" i mean its the automatically generated , adn that code doesnt work for mine

Comment: I mean im using a db