# remove _id from the return of MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have this.

```
app.get('/messages/all', async function (req, res) { 
const messages = await collection.find({}).toArray(); 
res.send(messages)
```

And i do this.

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:3000/messages/all
```

And this return this.

```
[{"_id":"5e973b8669e20600a59cd2b2","from":"user","msg":"ville"},{"_id":"5e973b8669e20600a59cd2b3","from":"bot","msg":"Nous sommes à Paris"}]
```

But i don't want the id. So i want to remove the _id.

Can i have help (i am not english and 19 dont judge me pls)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove \_id from mongo result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601219/remove-id-from-mongo-result)

Answer (score 2):

If `collection.find({})` is a mongo call, then you can exclude the _id.

```
collection.find({}, {_id: 0})
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

The second argument to the find is the projection.

Answer (score 2):

With nodejs and recent mongodb client (tested using 4.7.0), the syntax is:

```
collection.find({}, { projection: { _id: false } })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `false` like `{"_id": false}` MongoDB not to return _id from the collection

```
collection.find({},{"_id" : false}).toArray()
```

or you can use delete `_id` property from object javascript array

```
messages.forEach(function(v){ delete v._id});
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, use the `delete` operator to remove a prop from an object:

```js
let messages = collection.find({}).toArray()
messages = messages.map((doc) => {
  delete doc._id
  return doc
})
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete